# Unknown Meaning of ES6 Syntax

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Currently I am working on Learning React and Redux. I have found a boilerplate, and I am working on looking through all of the example code. My problem is I don't completely understand what a lot of this ES6 syntax means.

What I have learned so far is that `hello = () => "Hello";` would be equivalent to:

```
hello = function hello() {
  return "Hello";
};
```

Then changing the above to `hello = name => "Hello " + name;` would convert it to:

```
hello = function hello(name) {
  return "Hello " + name;
};
```

That all makes perfect sense, basically it is just shortening it down so you don't have to write the function and its return statement. Yet, I have come across some syntax that I cannot rap my head around. It is as follows:

```
const mapActionCreators = {
  increment: () => increment(1),
  doubleAsync
}
```

The above code is converted to:

```
var mapActionCreators = {
  increment: function (_increment) {
    function increment() {
      return _increment.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    increment.toString = function () {
      return _increment.toString();
    };

    return increment;
  }(function () {
    return increment(1);
  }),
  doubleAsync: doubleAsync
};
```

I understand that `() => increment(1)` in this case is being turned in to:

```
(function () {
    return increment(1);
}),
```

Overall I guess my question is, **how does `increment:` get converted in to:**

```
 increment: function (_increment) {
    function increment() {
      return _increment.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    increment.toString = function () {
      return _increment.toString();
    };

    return increment;
 }
```

**What is the meaning of the code?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrow functions capture the value of `this` from the scope they are created in.

`apply` lets you call a function and explicitly the value of `this` in it.

The rest of the code is just feeding the correct `this` to the function.

(And `toString` is making sure that the *right* function gets stringified if you try to stringify the generated function).